# How to Connect to Laravel FTP?

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I am creating an admin for a mobile app using `laravel.i` need to save images and pdf on the mobile server using FTP.
This is my code in `config/filesystem.php` :

```
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => '10.10.20.40',
    'username' => 'Username',
    'password' => 'Password',
    'root' => '',
    'port' => 21
 ],
```

And in my controller :

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put($name, fopen($file, 'r+'));
```

This works and saves the file in the route folder while I have subfolders in the root folder for storing different types of files, for example, images for pictures and PDF for pdf files. how to give the name of subfolders using single FTP?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this code instead of going through FTP as FTP is not considered save approach

```
if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
       $cover = $request->file('filename');
       $fileName = ('../public_html/myfolder/public/').time().'.'.$request->filename->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $request->filename->move('public_html/myfolder/public', $fileName);
       $users->files =   $fileName;
     }
     else{
       $users->files =   '/public/avatar.jpg';
     }
```

and in this path you can add checks as per file extensions e.g

```
$ext = $request->filename->getClientOriginalExtension();
if($ext =='pdf'){
    $request->filename->move('public_html/myfolder/public/PDF', $imageName);
}
```

and for all other extensions you can manage your path very simply

Comment: I wanted to do this using ftp but now Will try this code.

Comment: i tried this solution but was not able to implement. i was trying to copy images and pdf on an another server.

Comment: if you need to copy image on another server then you need to write api, or use cURL, this method won't work for another server

Answer (score 0):

The put function within the Storage class will accept a full path, relative to the root directory of the configured disk ([Storing Files - Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files)).

Using your code, and assuming you wished to upload $file to the 'images' folder via the FTP driver currently configured - you could use the following code:

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('images/'.$name, fopen($file,'$r+'));
```